# how to access ISecretKeyReader in ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I am registering multiple services within `ConfigureServices` for asp.net core 3.1 web api application and would like to access one service method in another service. Is this possible?

sample code, here I want to access `ISecretKeyReader` in second service registration, how?

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ISecretKeyReader, AzureKeyVaultReader>();
        services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        {
            //how to access ISecretKeyReader here?
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access other services like that:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISecretKeyReader, AzureKeyVaultReader>();
services.AddSingleton(sp =>
{
    var secretReader = sp.GetService<ISecretKeyReader>();
    // return other service
});
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. Could you please check the similar kind of question here and suggest me something? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62947917/how-to-access-isecretkeyreader-here-to-get-connection-string-from-azure-key-vaul